# set a users profile to default sharepoint image programatically

Tags: 2013, user-profile, visual-web-part, image

I am trying to create a custom web part which shows the current users photo and his name.

Also i am giving two buttons one for adding an image and another for setting it to default image or removing the image.

The functionality for adding a profile image is working fine but removing or setting it to a default image is pending. I need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));
// accountName is Active Directory account
UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
// PictureUrl is the property you need to set.. set it to Empty string..
userProfile["PictureUrl"].Value = string.Empty;
// commit the change
userProfile.Commit();
```

Added this code to the onclick of an image link. When i click on this it removes the image and set it to the default image

Answer (score 2):

I have copied the default image in SharePoint and using the below code to load the default image:

```
 imgUserProfilePagePicture.ImageUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_layouts/15/images/PersonPlaceholder.200x150x32.png";
```